# Call javascript function from PHP whilst page loads

Tags: php, javascript, function, undefined

I'm attempting to call a javascript function from a PHP loop. The call passes an id from the PHP loop and then is supposed to set a class based on whether it finds the id in a cookie. At the moment I am simply getting:

> ReferenceError: getFaveClass() is not defined

My code is the following -

```
?>
<script>getFaveClass(<?php echo $row->id; ?>);</script>
<?php
```

Is there something I am missing or a better way of doing this?

Comment: `PHP=server-side; JS=client-side`. It simply will not work

Comment: I realise the significance of the two languages but surely it's possible to call a function on page load? What would be the appropriate way of achieving this?

Comment: @SamuelCook In theory it is possible to call javascript function while PHP is generating the page. I've seen that trick used for progress bars. For example: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.flush.php#52147. But you'd need to flush the output to do something like that.

Comment: @SamuelCook just so you know for next time - it does work, see below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's nothing wrong with what you have written (although personally I'd use `json_encode` to ensure the value is properly handled).

All the error means is that you haven't defined the `getFaveClass` function. If it's in an external `.js` file, make sure you're including it.

Comment: Thanks for the help. This was a bit of a silly mistake - getFaveClass was in an external .js file and was being called at the bottom of the page - have moved it to the header and all is running fine.

Answer (score 0):

If the id is output, the data should be on the page when the script is executed. Echo-ing out PHP as initial data to a JavaScript call is fine. I suggest you check and see what is actually being output, rather than your PHP source, in order to debug JS errors.

Your problem is probably what happens if `$row->id == ""`.

Answer (score 0):

Have you declared the function `getFaveClass()` and is there a value in the `<?php echo $row->id; ?>`

Please check your function name to be exact including the case where you have been calling this.

Just check that it should run. AS i can't see anything wrong with your what so ever code you have shared.